# Qt - Child widgets are not shown

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building a multi-window app and so far creates and shows MainWidget with 8 buttons. My next step is to make each button open a new window which in Qt terms is a child of QWidget. I keep all my buttons and new windows (which should be opened upon a button is clicked) in QVectors. It all compiles with no warnings or errors, however, when I click a button, the corresponding QWidget window is not shown.

**mainwidget.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSignalMapper>

#include "examwindow.h"


namespace Ui { class MainWidget; }

class MainWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWidget();

private:
    Ui::MainWidget *ui;

    int nExams;
    QVector<QString> titles;
    QVector<QPushButton*> examButtons;
    QGridLayout* mainWidgetLayout;
    QVector<ExamWindow*> examWindows;

public slots:
    void clickedExamW (); 
};

#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

**mainwidget.cpp**

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include "ui_mainwidget.h"
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <iostream>
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /**
     * @brief Resize the main window size in proportion to the desktop size
     */
    double ratio = 0.7;
    resize(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry(this).size() * ratio);

    /**
     * @brief Set the main window position in the desktop center
     */
    QDesktopWidget dw;
    int width = this->frameGeometry().width();
    int height = this->frameGeometry().height();
    int screenWidth = dw.screen() -> width();
    int screenHeight = dw.screen() -> height();
    this->setGeometry((screenWidth / 2) - (width / 2), (screenHeight / 2) - (height / 2), width, height);

    /**
     * Set the button titles
     */
    titles.push_back("FCE - 2008");
    titles.push_back("CAE - 2008");
    titles.push_back("CPE - 2008");
    titles.push_back("ЕГЭ");
    titles.push_back("FCE - 2015");
    titles.push_back("CAE - 2015");
    titles.push_back("CPE - 2015");
    titles.push_back("User's Format");

    /**
     * Create buttons
     */
    nExams = 8;         // Number of exams

    examButtons.resize(nExams);
    for(int i = 0; i < nExams; i++) {
        examButtons[i] = new QPushButton(titles[i]);
        examButtons[i]->setMinimumSize(QSize(150, 150));
        examButtons[i]->setMaximumSize(QSize(500, 500));
        examButtons[i]->setObjectName(titles[i]);
        connect(examButtons[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clickedExamW()));
    }

    /**
     * Add exam buttons to the main widget layout
     */
    mainWidgetLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
    for(int i = 0; i < nExams; i++)
        if (i < nExams / 2)
            mainWidgetLayout -> addWidget(examButtons[i], i, 0);
        else
            mainWidgetLayout -> addWidget(examButtons[i], i - nExams / 2, 1);

    /**
     * Create exam windows
     */
    examWindows.resize(nExams);
    for(int i = 0; i < nExams; i++) {
        examWindows[i] = new ExamWindow(this);
        examWindows[i]->setWindowTitle(titles[i]);
    }



}

void MainWidget::clickedExamW() {

    QObject *senderObj = sender();
    QString senderObjName = senderObj->objectName();
    for(int i = 0; i < nExams; i++)
        if (senderObjName == titles[i]) {
            this->setWindowTitle(titles[i]); // WORKS - it changes the title
            examWindows[i]->show();          // DOES NOT WORK - no win shown 
        }
}


MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**examwindow.h**

```
#ifndef EXAMWINDOW_H
#define EXAMWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

class ExamWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExamWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // EXAMWINDOW_H
```

**examwindow.cpp**

```
#include "examwindow.h"

ExamWindow::ExamWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you want to have ExamWindow as the separate window or as the child widget of mainWindow? I think your windows have the wrong position and you did no see it. You may check isVisible.

Comment: I want ExamWindow to be a child of MainWindow not to handle memory management. Visually, it should be a window that opens above the MainWindow.

UPD: I make my ExamWindow QDialogs and it worked. I wonder how QDialog is different from QWidget in that capacity.

Comment: [`QDialog` is a top level window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details). While [`QWidget` can be a top level window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#top-level-and-child-widgets), it isn't if it has a parent set.

Comment: `QDesktopWidget dw;` - it's wrong. You need to use `QApplication::desktop()` to obtain desktop widget instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way, how do you create widgets is ok (`examWindows[i] = new ExamWindow(this);`). But:

```
ExamWindow::ExamWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent, Qt::Window)
{}
```

You need to directly [specify a flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) that you need a "window" widget.

Or, if you don't want to set parent widget, you may set [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute for automatic releasing memory. Note, that in this case you will have an invalid pointer inside your `examWindows` vector. It may be resolved if you will use next declaration: `QVector<QPointer<ExamWindow>> examWindows;`

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: it turned out that the problem was in this line:

```
examWindows[i] = new ExamWindow(this);
```

If I remove 'this', making my windows parentless, it works as intended. I'm puzzled why and I guess I have to delete them now manually.